# How or where to download my root CA for AWS IoT?

Tags: certificate, aws-iot

I just created a thing in AWS-iot. Then I browsed to create the certificates for the thing, with is ok and I am able to retrieve them. Before the final step (press the btn `activate`) I see a message that offered me to download the Root CA certificate like in the picture below:
[image]

Then when I press in the `Download` link I am redirected to the following page:
[image]

And then the only link of the previous page redirects me to this follow page:
[image]
[image]

where we can find many links to many certificates.

Is this the way AWS is using to allow us to download the ROOT CA certificate? And if yes which one is the one described in the first picture `A root CA for AWS IoT`? If not where is this certificate located?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Download it from [here](https://www.amazontrust.com/repository/AmazonRootCA1.pem).

Read this for future reference: [AWS IoT Certificates](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/server-authentication.html#server-authentication-certs).

cheers,
ram