# How to resolve unable to get local issuer certificate issue

Tags: node.js, ssl, ssl-certificate

While making a fetch call in nodejs, I am getting this error

```
{"errorType":"TypeError","errorMessage":"fetch failed","cause":{"errorType":"Error","errorMessage":"unable to get local issuer certificate","code":"UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY",
```

By seeing other solutions, I have setup this in my `yarn config`

```
NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED: '0',
cafile: 'C:\\Users\\vishnu\\.certs\\all.pem',
```

In `all.pem`, I have downloaded the certificate of the API I am requesting, by downloading it from browser.

But still, I am getting same error. Please help

Comment: The `cafile` does not expect the browser certificate - which is (usually) not a CA certificate. It instead expects the root CA which has issued the browser certificate. This is only the same in case of self-signed certificate, where the certificate is signed by the certificate itself.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Thanks for reply, I need to get the aws CA certificate, how to get that ?

Comment: Not sure if it this - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59293442/how-or-where-to-download-my-root-ca-for-aws-iot

Comment: @SteffenUllrich How to skip the SSL certificate validation. As I mentioned above the setting the flag to 0 didn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, I am using **sam local**, to run the lambda where my code is executing.
SAM uses docker containers to run the lambda.

I have set the `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED: 0` in my local machine, which can't be referred by docker. That was the issue.

After setting the `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED: 0` in my template.yml, it resolved.

Due to security issues, if you don't want to ignore the SSL verification, you can also do `NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS: 'cert.pem'`.
`cert.pem` is the root certificate of the website that you are making the HTTPS call.
You can download it from browser.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).